# Specify images for iPad in Xcode like @2x for iPhone 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, ipad

I have upgraded my current target to iPad and made a universal app and the time for adjusting my iphone app to ipad would decrease significantly if there is an answer for this question.

By this time everybody know that if you have a image called "*football.png*" and want support for Retina Display you should double the size of the image and call it "*football@2x.png*".

My question is if there is something for iPad like *football@iPad_which_is_another_size.png*?

If there isn't a way to do this, do I have to connect every image to an IBOutlet and set the frame programmatically?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> In iOS 4.0 and later, it is possible
>   to mark individual resource files as
>   usable only on a specific type of
>   device
>   To associate a resource file with a
>   particular device, you add a custom
>   modifier string to its filename. The
>   inclusion of this modifier string
>   yields filenames with the following
>   format:

```
 <basename><device>.<filename_extension>
```

To load the iPad specific resources you should use `~ipad`. Example: create the image named `AwesomeImage~ipad.png` and load with `[UIImage imageNamed:@"AwesomeImage.png"]` like you do for retina display image.

For more information: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html
At "iOS Supports Device-Specific Resources" section.

Comment: A great answer, though the deployment target set to 3.0 so I can't use this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to get the OS to pick it automatically for you, like there is for the Retina display.  But, you could create a convenience method to return your filenames for you like:

```
-(NSString*) myImageFilename:(NSString*)baseName withExtension:(NSString*)ext {

 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@@iPadSize.%@"];
 } else {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@.%@"];
 } 

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this alternative solution means that I have to connect every image to a IBOutlet in my header file. I am, like I commented in Eimanas answer, creating an universal app which only creates a MainWindow-iPad.xib. But I'm considerating to use the other alternative when upgrading current target to iPad. Does that sound like the most appropriate solution?