# UIImageViews, xibs, and suffixes (@2x, ~iphone, ~ipad)

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Specify images for iPad in Xcode like @2x for iPhone 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535630/specify-images-for-ipad-in-xcode-like-2x-for-iphone-4)

I'm having trouble finding current conclusive information about how to properly use images based on device classes (Apple documentation being like a maze of twisted corridors, all alike). My sense is that this is something that has evolved a bit over time. Suppose I want to support non-retina and retina iphones and ipads with different images.

Here are all the permutations of filenames that I can think of:

```
image.png
image@2x.png

image~iphone.png
image~ipad.png
image@2x~iphone.png
image@2x~ipad.png
```

I could do this:

```
myview.xib
myview~ipad.xib
```

Suppose I have four devices, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPad 2, iPad 3 (or 'new iPad' for purists).

Let's talk about how I would set up my xibs (i.e. I add a UIImageView, what do I choose for an image?) to use the appropriate image and how, if I use code, `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]` would behave.

It's my understanding that in code I could fall back on `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` but I'm not convinced that I need to.

If someone could explain what will and won't work, I know that it'll be a help to me, and I suspect to others. If I've somehow duplicated another SO question I couldn't find, well, we can close this up and link to it. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535630/specify-images-for-ipad-in-xcode-like-2x-for-iphone-4?rq=1

Comment: @ПавелОганесян That is a helpful link! I know that I am still having some trouble getting the proper images to load with this information in hand.

Comment: Ah, worth noting that it important to clean to your build if you overwrite a file with the same name. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in iphone xib you have to use image~iphone. on ipad xib you have to use image~ipad. @2x is automatic selected when file is needed.

Comment: Ok, cool. So imageNamed will respect all the suffixes, and the xib part works as you mention. Thanks!